# CSS: Circle arc of 1/8 length

Tags: css, border, geometry

**Only by using CSS**, I am trying to create an arc of a circle of some width and color, which lenght is 1/8 of the circle lenght or even smaller (as I would like to achieve an effect of gaps between each segments of the the whole circle. Please see the illustration.

[image]

I tried combination of border radius and border style, but that get me only 1/4.

**See Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/uc8wvtfb/

How can this be accomplished only by using CSS?

HTML:

```
<div class="arc"></div>
```

CSS:

```
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
border-radius: 50%;
border-color: transparent transparent red transparent;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 0px 10px 10px 10px;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way of doing it: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0s9zmxvu/1/). It's one dashed border on top of another. You can then adjust the size of the "gaps" between the dashes by adjusting the `transform: rotate(30deg)` value.

**CSS**

```
.arc {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 15px dashed red;
    position: relative;
}

.arc:after {
    content: '';
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: -15px;
    left: -15px;
    border: 15px dashed red;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg);
    transform: rotate(30deg);
}
```